# Problems installing my USB Wifi dongle

Tags: networking, wireless, software-installation, usb-modem

I tried connecting my new TP Link TL-WN823N, and if it did show me several available Wifi network, I could not connect to mine (it basically hanged, I never could enter my password). I tried following some instructions here and there, and now I can't connect to anything anymore, and there are no lights anymore on the dongle.

Could someomne please help me? I'm on Xubuntu 16.04.

Edit:

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 22b8:2e24 Motorola PCS 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046a:b090 Cherry GmbH 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And here is iwconfig

```
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

enp0s20f0u9  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enxa42bb0bcf267  unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to askubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better and more stable driver available. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

Reboot and tell us if the performance has improved.

Comment: Seems like rtl8192cu-dkms hasn't been updated to 16.04 yet. I'm having a "Unable to locate package rtl8192cu"

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.